# Shifting in the plot of the time series and its ARIMA model

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am a self learner, and I am trying to learn how to do times series analysis in R.
I generated a sythentic data, and try to recover its model using ARIMA modeling. Here is my code:

```
library(tseries)
library(forecast)
a<- 0.7567
t<-c(0:100)  # c collection
c<-rnorm(length(t+1), mean = 0, sd = 0.5)
############  Data of the times series  #############
yy = rep(NA,100)
yy[[1]] <- 2
for (i in 2:101)  {
yy[i] <- a*yy[i-1]+3*c[i] 
} 
y <- ts(yy,frequency=12)
acf(y,na.action = na.exclude)
fit = auto.arima(y,stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE);
coefficients(fit)
matplot(cbind(y,fitted(fit)),type='l')
mse(y, fitted(fit))
```

Every thing was fine (as I supposed), however the plot of the obtained model is just a shift of the real data (as appeared in the following graph). Is there an explanation of such obtained result ?
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suspect this is a misunderstanding of the software rather than a question about time series analysis.  However, your code as given doesn't work: `t` is undefined and you don't provide the name of the library for `auto.arima`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, yes I mistakenly delete t, I will edit the code to be as appeared in my editor. @whuber

Answer (score -1):

I have a guess based upon many, many time series analyses.

It appears to me that a first differencing operator is in play as the 1 period out prediction (model) is the same as the value 1 period ago . Perhaps your auto.arima isn't so auto ..  and is introducing self-cancelling structure along with an unwarranted d>0  .

Examine the so-called best model and report it . If you post your actual simulated series I will submit it to another "expert" and I will report the results back to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but would you please tell me what is the so-called " best model"?

Comment: doesn;t auto.arima deliver a model  for the data you simulated which would then lead to the"model values" ?